# JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 61 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am porting a Google Chrome extension to become a Firefox add-on. I eventually got it working to be a temporary add-on, but it needed to have an ID for me to keep it on file (which is what I want to do). I got past all that but now I'm having trouble closing the manifest.json. When I try to close the json Firefox gives me the error seen in the title.

Tried many different forms of brackets closing, such as:

```
 ]
}

]}

}
```

and more.

```
],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*",
    "*://*.vrv.co/*",
    "*://*.dlvr1.net/*",
    "*://*.akamaized.net/*"
  ]
}
```

As told in the title, I am getting the errors in the closing bracket. Please excuse me if this is a really dumb thing to overlook, I program in Lua and web development is not my thing. This block of code should be all you need to reproduce the problem, but again I'm a new guy at this so let me know if more is needed. I'm also new to stack overflow so I wanted to keep it to a minimum as requested.

It should be able to load onto Firefox, but it gives me the error message seen in the title.

Whole json file is here:

```
{ "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "ihegfgnkffeibpmnajnoiemkcmlbmhmi",
      "strict_min_version": "42.0",
      "strict_max_version": "*",
   "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Crunchyroll HTML5",
  "version": "0.14.4",
  "description": "A fully fledged HTML5 player for Crunchyroll.",
  "author": "Jeppe Rune Mortensen <jepperm@gmail.com>",
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon16.png",
    "32": "assets/icon32.png",
    "48": "assets/icon48.png",
    "64": "assets/icon64.png",
    "96": "assets/icon96.png",
    "128": "assets/icon128.png"

  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
        "patch.js",
        "content-script.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": [
        "*://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
        "patch-worker.firefox.js",
        "content-script.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "vendor/JavascriptSubtitlesOctopus/*",
    "fonts/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*",
    "*://*.vrv.co/*",
    "*://*.dlvr1.net/*",
    "*://*.akamaized.net/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: We need to see the full JSON file.

Comment: Added the whole json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: Please use the other answer. I misread the spec.**

**EDIT - Better answer now that the JSON has been provided**

Here is working JSON as validated by the parser I have linked below:

```
{ "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "ihegfgnkffeibpmnajnoiemkcmlbmhmi",
      "strict_min_version": "42.0",
      "strict_max_version": "*",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "Crunchyroll HTML5",
      "version": "0.14.4",
      "description": "A fully fledged HTML5 player for Crunchyroll.",
      "author": "Jeppe Rune Mortensen <jepperm@gmail.com>",
      "icons": {
        "16": "assets/icon16.png",
        "32": "assets/icon32.png",
        "48": "assets/icon48.png",
        "64": "assets/icon64.png",
        "96": "assets/icon96.png",
        "128": "assets/icon128.png"
      },
      "background": {
        "scripts": [
          "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
          "background.js"
        ]
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*"
          ],
          "js": [
            "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
            "patch.js",
            "content-script.js"
          ],
          "run_at": "document_start"
        },
        {
          "all_frames": true,
          "matches": [
            "*://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer*"
          ],
          "js": [
            "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
            "patch-worker.firefox.js",
            "content-script.js"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "web_accessible_resources": [
        "vendor/JavascriptSubtitlesOctopus/*",
        "fonts/*"
      ],
      "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*",
        "*://*.vrv.co/*",
        "*://*.dlvr1.net/*",
        "*://*.akamaized.net/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Fundamentally your problem boils down to inconsistent indenting making it hard to tell where the problem lies. The actual issue was that you were missing 2 additional closing braces `}` at the end of the file. You can use parsers as I've linked below in my original answer to try and help you debug these issues.

**Original answer before the full JSON was provided**

If you input your last bit of code you provided into this website you can see whether it's valid: http://json.parser.online.fr/ Spoiler: it says that it is. This should be your first clue that the problem is, in fact, not with this last chunk as you currently believe it to be. For reference, this is what I've copied into that parser:

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*",
    "*://*.vrv.co/*",
    "*://*.dlvr1.net/*",
    "*://*.akamaized.net/*"
  ]
}
```

Judging based on what you copied in since you have not given us the full JSON file I believe you have included an extra closing bracket `}` somewhere above this section. This is because if you pay attention to the indentation of what you have copied in:

```
],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*",
    "*://*.vrv.co/*",
    "*://*.dlvr1.net/*",
    "*://*.akamaized.net/*"
  ]
}
```

the closing list bracket `]` has the same indentation as the closing object brace `}`. Of course this could be a problem with how you've copied your code into StackOverflow, but I don't have any other clues to go off of due to the fact you have not provided us with the rest of the file.

Comment: I've added the whole JSON at the bottom of the page. I noticed that removing the beginning bracket at the absolute start of the json solves line 60, but creates a syntax error on line 1.

Comment: I've fixed it up for you now :)

Comment: @Shawn Clake You need to look at the spec for the manifest.  The two brackets that are missing are near the top of the file.  The other answer to this question has it correct.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the specification for the manifest.json here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json

I would suggest using a JSON editing tool such as https://jsoneditoronline.org/ to build your JSON, that way you won't forget to add the correct bracket pair...

Now that I see the whole file, it appears there was a missing } for the "gecko": object and a } for the "browser_specific_settings":

Here is the file with all brackets matched.

```
{ "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "ihegfgnkffeibpmnajnoiemkcmlbmhmi",
      "strict_min_version": "42.0",
      "strict_max_version": "*"
      }
    },
   "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Crunchyroll HTML5",
  "version": "0.14.4",
  "description": "A fully fledged HTML5 player for Crunchyroll.",
  "author": "Jeppe Rune Mortensen <jepperm@gmail.com>",
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon16.png",
    "32": "assets/icon32.png",
    "48": "assets/icon48.png",
    "64": "assets/icon64.png",
    "96": "assets/icon96.png",
    "128": "assets/icon128.png"

  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
        "patch.js",
        "content-script.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": [
        "*://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "vendor/browser-polyfill.min.js",
        "patch-worker.firefox.js",
        "content-script.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "vendor/JavascriptSubtitlesOctopus/*",
    "fonts/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*",
    "*://*.vrv.co/*",
    "*://*.dlvr1.net/*",
    "*://*.akamaized.net/*"
  ]
}
```